# PHPOffice PHPPresentation lose original styling on saving pptx

Tags: php, phpoffice, phppresentation

I have simple code that:

1. Load template pptx (*)
2. Duplicate few slides
3. Hydrate those slides with values (just replacing place-holder texts)
4. Save result to new file

Unfortunately PHPOffice's PHPPresentation is unable to retain slide styling present in template.

Slides saved in step 4. are all white (default styling).

*Is there a way to explicitly copy that styling? Is it PHPPresentation limitation 'cause it's unable to read styling or something?*

(*) Described issue persist for ppt/odp too. No styling is retained.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! I've tried manually copying the Layout, but it didn't do anything. Did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: Nope. Maybe one could try to copy relevant xml parts (PPTX is after all *just* zipped xml ;) ) But for me styling-less pptx filled needs.

Comment: @przemo_li have you resolved this issue or still pending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is that PHPPresentation (oldly PHPPowerPoint) can't load Slide Layout and Slide Master.

This bug has an opened issue : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/161.

Comment: At least to some degree. Visit the link for instruction on how to transfer that styling.

Comment: @przemo_li i have tried but not working at my end.. can you help me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: $templatepath = public_path('images/samples/sample.pptx');
$pptReader = IOFactory::createReader('PowerPoint2007');
$oPHPPresentation = $pptReader->load("$templatepath");

$xmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($oPHPPresentation, 'PowerPoint2007');
$newsamplepath = storage_path('app/public/ppts/sample'.str_random(5).'.pptx');
$xmlWriter->save($newsamplepath);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902336/phppresentation-lose-styling-when-we-copy-from-particular-path-and-saving-new-pp  
feel free to answer i have uploaded the question also