# PHPPresentation lose styling when we copy from particular path and saving new pptx

Tags: php, phpoffice, phppresentation

I have search around google regarding PHPPresentation but nothing found. I know this type of question already asked ([PHPOffice PHPPresentation lose original styling on saving pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472573/phpoffice-phppresentation-lose-original-styling-on-saving-pptx)) and i have checked the answer of this particular question (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/161)

I have done according to above answer but its not working at all. Here is my below code:-

```
$templatepath = public_path('images/samples/sample.pptx');
$pptReader = IOFactory::createReader('PowerPoint2007');
$oPHPPresentation = $pptReader->load("$templatepath");
//save pptx
$xmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($oPHPPresentation, 'PowerPoint2007');
$newsamplepath = storage_path('app/public/ppts/sample'.str_random(5).'.pptx');
$xmlWriter->save($newsamplepath);
```

My sample.pptx looks like below:-

[image]

Output coming like below:-
[image]

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: It looks like a missing image primarily. Perhaps the template links to an external image file and you haven't brought that across when you copied it? Without seeing the pptx file it's hard to know, really.

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure the implication of the github issue you linked was that the code presented there was the solution. It was merely part of some analysis.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for response. You have any alternative to resolve this issue?

Comment: well first I suggest you check what I mentioned in the first comment. Secondly make sure you have the latest version of the library which includes the merge which was the result of closing the issue you mentioned. It does note in that discussion that the library is far from perfect. Perhaps it has other issues.

Comment: @ADyson i will add images dyanmically but the issue is template styling check the left side bar of the sample.pptx  or you know some other library ?

Comment: i have the latest version of PHPPResentation i have installed using composer